# Deriving time period of oscillation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, time, harmonic-oscillator, equilibrium

[image]

I have attached the question image.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook's law $F=-kx$ . If $\tau$ is the torque on board , then force at the spring, $F=\frac{\tau}{L}$ and $\tau=I\alpha$ , where $I=\frac{mL^2}{3}$ , M.I of rod about one of its end . U can replace x by $x=L\theta$ and appliying to hook's law yield 
$I\dfrac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}=-L^2k\theta$
this gives
$\omega=\sqrt{\frac{L^2k}{I}}$. 
Therefore,
time period,
$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{I}{L^2k}}$
substituting your values, you can arrive at a simple value (I am not going to do it here).